# Recursion method continues after returning value?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm writing a quick Java recursion method that, given a root folder and filename, searches your files for said file name.

```
import Java.io.File;

public static String searchForFile(File currentFolder, String filename)
{
    try
    {
        File[] path = currentFolder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
        {
            if (path[i].isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("Directory: " + path[i].toString());
                searchForFile(path[i], filename);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File: " + path[i].toString());

                if(path[i].getName().equals(filename))
                {
                    System.out.println("Your file has been found!";
                    return path[i].toString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null; // Omitting this line yields compiling errors, not sure why?
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Hello, enter the root folder and file name.");
    String rootFolder = "Desktop";
    String fileName = "Hello.txt";

    File f = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\" + rootFolder);
    searchForFile(f, fileName);

}
```

The program itself technically works, however `searchForFile()` keeps iterating even after the requested file is found. For example, I'd get an output such as:

```
File: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Stuff\NotHello.txt
**File: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Stuff\Hello.txt**

Your file has been found!

File: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Stuff\AlsoNotHello.txt
File: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Stuff\StillNotHello.txt
File: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\My Stuff\WhyIsThisMethodStillRunning.txt
```

I've been scratching my head at this for awhile now. I thought `return` always exits the method, so why does the recursion continue even after it returns a value? I haven't found any similar questions asked, so any help would be much appreciated!

(Also, how could I edit the method so that it returns a blank `""` string if the requested file is not found?)

Answer (score 2):

You are returning from the innermost call, when you've found the file. But when you are scanning a directory, you are not using the return value.

Change this:

```
searchForFile(path[i], filename);
```

to:

```
String result = searchForFile(path[i], filename);
if (result != null) {
    return result;
}
```

---

The `return null;` in the bottom of your method is there because all methods needs to return a value. No matter if the file is found or not. If the file is not found within the current directory (or one of its subdirectories), you can `return null;` to indicate that it wasn't found.

Side suggestion: Use `Optional` in Java 8 instead of `null`.

Comment: Hi Simon, your advice worked, thank you! If you don't mind, can you help explain why this worked?

Why does using `return searchForFile(path[i], filename);` not work?

Comment: @RyanA. Because if you do that you will return a value no matter if the file was found or not. Let's say that your file is in `dir2` but `dir1` also exists. `dir1` is searched first, so then you do `return searchForFile(dir1, filename)` but that returns `null` as there is no file there. So then you `return null;` and voilá, your program will say that it couldn't find the file you were looking for.